# Is every season of Prison Break continued from the previous? Does the prison break story takes place throughout all seasons?

Tags: prison-break

I'm planning to watch Prison Break series. It has 5 seasons. But I don't know if I have to watch all seasons to understand the prison break/escape story.

Is there any case that for example first 2 seasons has a complete story and then next 2 have a different prison break/escape story? So I can watch only first 2 seasons without feeling incomplete?

Or there is only one story and it takes place throughout the all seasons?

Comment: Why not simply watch? Back in the day nobody knew ahead of time of what would happen, whether the first season would be a mere 13 eps or whether it would get a full season order (20+ eps), whether it would be renewed etc. We simply... watched. And if the stories kept gripping us, we kept watching. And when they didn't, we stopped.

Comment: I find it useful to know if a series builds up to a massive cliffhanger and then gets cancelled before I start watching.  Having said that, this is the sort of information you can find on Wikipedia I assume so I imagine that's why the downvotes.

Comment: Prison Break had four seasons with in total over 70 episodes, and then got an additional 9 episode season ten years after it ended.

Comment: @BCdotWEB that was one of reasons I asked this question. Sometimes it's good to know beforehand when you're going to watch a bulk of episodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one story and it continues from one season to the next.  The same characters are involved, at least for Seasons 1 to 4.  (I haven't seen Season 5 myself.)  There are multiple literal prison breaks, but not one per season.

I think you could watch the first two seasons and walk away with a complete story feeling.  The story does continue, but S2 left off at a good stopping point IIRC.  Seasons 3 and 4 are more closely tied, so if you want to watch S3, you probably want to watch S4 as well for closure.

As I said, I haven't seen S5 myself, but given the large real-world time gap between S4 and S5, I'm assuming it's a more self-contained story, perhaps with some references back to the earlier seasons.  I don't know how many of the original cast return to reprise their roles.